# Stroke Effect on Arabic Text At Junctions

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, stroke

Briefly, I am having a problem performing a simple stroke operation on arabic text in an html5 2D canvas.

Arabic text has this property of characters changing forms and merging together when they're next to each other. Apparently, how js handles text stroke is by taking every character by itself and operating on them separately. When the characters are then rendered to the screen, the boundaries of characters becomes visible resulting in leaking stroke colors at the joints.

On the left is the result produced by Javascript's stroke function. On the right is a correct result created with Photoshop (different font).

[image]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you draw the stroked version on top of the filled one.

Do the inverse and everything will look as you wanted :

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "200px Al Tharikh, Arial"
var txt = 'مثال';

ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

// change the stroke style
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

// first draw the stroke
ctx.strokeText(txt , 100, 0);

// then draw the fill
ctx.fillText(txt , 100, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="200" width="500"></canvas>
```

Ps : if you want to get only the external stroke, then you can use [globalCompositeOperations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) :

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "200px Al Tharikh, Arial"
var txt = 'مثال';

ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

// change the stroke style
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;


// first draw a larger stroke
ctx.strokeText(txt , 100, 0);

// then set the gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

// then draw the filled version which will act as an "eraser"
ctx.fillText(txt , 100, 0);

// reset the gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

```css
canvas{background: ivory;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="200" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been using fabricjs as the main canvas library, and having no experience nor knowledge that stroking is done in 2 steps like that, I figured it would be a much deeper problem. I've bodged my way through in fabric.js by filling after stroking every time, but I certainly hope Kangax would fix this problem in the later fabricjs releases.